Can I rename a custom Datadog metric and retain prior metric history?
I am recording a custom metric account_created and presenting this metric on several dashboards. I would like to rename the metric to account_created_success and retain all of its history.
I would like to be able to display the new metric on the dashboard but still have the history of the original metric be present on the dashboard. Ideally, I would do this without adding both the new and old metrics to the dashboard.
